# Passing sanitized input with function does not work

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I've been having a problem the past few days where I've narrowed the problem as shown below.  The passing of the parameters works fine if I don't use it with the custom distance function.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  As of now, I'm just sanitizing the field manually and hard coding it into the query.

WORKS (returns correct results):

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM providers WHERE distance('42.8','-73.9',lat,lon)<25");
$sth->execute();
```

DOES NOT WORK (returns all providers):

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM providers WHERE distance('42.8','-73.9',lat,lon)<:radius");
$sth->execute(array(":radius" =>25));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not real familiar with PDO, but possibly it is because you are passing an `int` and the statement treats values as a `string` by default.  See the manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php and look under `input_parameters` for more.  You could always try using `bind_param()` to get your data into the correct type before executing your statement.

Comment: Do you think it matters that this is sqlite? (I should have thought to add that as a tag).  SQLite has a loose datatype system.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure (not familiar with SQLite) but, if I were to make an assumption, perhaps the datatype matters because you are using a prepared statement.  I would guess that it has less to do with SQLite datatype system and more to do with PDO wanting more details about the data it is working with.

Comment: Ok... I'm going to be AFK for a while... but I'll try the bind_param() later tonight and report back.

Comment: So I just tested it.  Interestingly, when "$radius=25", $sth->bindParam(':radius', $radius,PDO::PARAM_INT) works, and $sth->bindParam(':radius', $radius); does not.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed Glad it worked out for you. I had a similar problem when I mis-matched some datatypes with MySQL using prepared statements with the mysqli interface.  That is what made me think it was something with the interface and not your DB vendor.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:
I'm a little new to PDO myself, but I found this to work for me:

```
$radius = 25;
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM providers WHERE distance('42.8','-73.9',lat,lon)<:radius");
$query_params = array( 
        ':radius' => $radius
    ); 
$sth = $db->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY)); // forgot

$sth -> execute($query_params);
```

Comment: youv'e essentially changed nothing. directly passing an array v.s. creating an array var and then passing that var are fundamentally the same as par as the `->execute()` function is concerned.

Comment: Sorry - you're right. I forgot the //forgot line I'm assuming it does something to the PDO